# xcolor in printed documents

Tags: color

What is the right way of using colors in a document ought for printing?

I am always simply using the `xcolor` package. Consider for example

```
\documentclass[margin = 12mm]{standalone}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{foo}{rgb}{.4, .8, .2}

\begin{document}
Some \textcolor{foo}{example} text.
\color{red}\raisebox{.1em}{\rule{.3em}{.3em}}
\end{document}
```

[image: green-ish colored text closed with a red square]

Recently I came across a Reddit post (https://www.reddit.com/r/LaTeX/comments/d1tw6c/resource_for_best_packages_to_use_or_to_avoid/eztwtms), in which user u/0xe4524ffe comments:

> Avoid color and xcolor packages, they mess up cmyk colors, make text printed with color ink instead of just black(they put insane amount of repeated "0 0 0 rg" instead of one "0 g" in pdf stream).

My local `xcolor.sty` (2016/05/11 v2.12) ends with

```
1456 ...
1457 \color{black}
1458 \endinput
```

And the color `black` is according to

```
\extractcolorspecs{black}{\model}{\black}\black
```

defined as a simple gray colorspace `0`.

As there is no real solution given in the Reddit post on how to correctly use color and xcolor evaluates `black` (so everything with no color set) to `0`, my question is

**Is this answer still up-to-date and if so, how does one use color correctly?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It all depends on the color model you want to use. The default is rgb, so black is `0 0 0`.  You can load the package with the option `cmyk` and everything will be defined in cmyk.
Or redefine colors in another model, for example:

```
\pdfcompresslevel=0
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{black}{gray}{0}
\begin{document}    
\textcolor{black}{foo}

\definecolor{black}{rgb}{0,0,0}
\textcolor{black}{foo}

\definecolor{black}{cmyk}{0,0,0,1}
\textcolor{black}{foo}

\end{document}
```

the PDF then looks like:

```
stream
0 g 0 G
0 g 0 G
0 g 0 G
0 g 0 G
BT
/F8 9.9626 Tf 148.712 657.235 Td [(fo)-28(o)]TJ
0 g 0 G
0 0 0 rg 0 0 0 RG
 0 -11.955 Td [(fo)-28(o)]TJ
0 g 0 G
0 0 0 1 k 0 0 0 1 K
 0 -11.955 Td [(fo)-28(o)]TJ
0 g 0 G
0 g 0 G
 154.421 -543.96 Td [(1)]TJ
0 g 0 G
ET

endstream
```

you can also define the model for a single use of `\textcolor` e.g.:

```
\textcolor[gray]{0}{foo}
```